# Flash navbar with wordpress?

Tags: flash, wordpress

Does anybody know if it is possible to create a wordpress template with a flash navbar?  Perhaps you could point me to some examples? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to retrieve your pages url from wordpress (probably using get_pages() and parsing the info you need) and send the result to flash, using flashvars for instance.